# Find complement of given expression using Boolean algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Find the complement of
$xy(y+y'z) + x'z$

I solve this problem but get 3 different solution by using 3 different methods (rules of boolean algebra)

Solution that I get each time

1. $\quad x'z'+xy'+y'z'$
2. $\quad xy+xyz'$
3. $\quad y'z'$

Comment: xy(y + y'z) + x'z = xyy + xyy'z + x'z = xy + x'z.

Comment: @MikeSmith  please read the question again (find complement)

Comment: Please answer this question

Comment: What is 2 in BA?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  I can't understand please explain

Comment: It seems to me that you are using a "rule": $x+x=2x$, but in BA $x+x=x$

Comment: But still the problem is same

Comment: Please solve this question

Answer (score 1):

Let us give the above expression as $f(x,y,z)$, and exploit the laws of Boolean Algebra. First, we will simplify the above expression.
$$
\begin{split}
 f(x,y,z) &  = xy(y+y'z) + x'z & \space \space (\text{Distributivity})\\
 & = xyy +xyy'z + x'z & \space \space (\text{Idempotence, Complement}) \\
 & = xy +x'z & 
\end{split}
$$

Its complement is given taking the complement of the expression above.
$$
\begin{split}
 f'(x,y,z) &  = (xy +x'z)' & \space \space (\text{Distributivity})\\
 & = (xy)'(x'z)' & \space \space (\text{De Morgan}) \\
 & = (x' + y')(x + z') & \space \space (\text{De Morgan, Double Negation}) \\
 & = xx' + x'z' + xy' + y'z' & \space \space (\text{Distributivity}) \\
 & = x'z' + xy' + y'z' & \space \space (\text{Complement}) \\
 & = (x+z)' + xy' + (y+z)' & \space \space (\text{De Morgan}) \\
\end{split}
$$

Assuming you are required to leave the answer in the canonical conjunctive normal form, point 1 which you have written is the correct answer. The trick is to simplify the expression, then take the compliment of the expression.